# Implementing a directory structure in Grunt

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

I am working on a project using coffeescript and want to have a directory structure like:

```
project/
    Gruntfile
    common/
        *.coffee
        *.spec.coffee
        *.scaffold.coffee
        bin/
        test/
    server/
        *.coffee
        *.spec.coffee
        *.scaffold.coffee
        bin/
        test/
    client/
        *.html
        *.css
        *.coffee
        *.spec.coffee
        *.scaffold.coffee
        bin/
        test/
```

Where coffee files get compiled to bin, spec.coffee and scaffold.coffee get compiled to test.  There are directories containing static files that are not shown.

Is there an easy/standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

this is a general question so the general answer is: yes, most grunt plugins have easy ways to configure each task, identify source files and where the output gets generated.

take a look at the documentation for grunt-contrib-coffee, shows lots of examples of how to config directories to process coffee files including options to flatten sub-directories, etc.

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee